# Setting seed in R

Tags: r

If I want to generate several random variables in R, all using the same seed, do I have to set the seed every time? For example, should I write:

```
set.seed(123456) 
x = runif(1000,0,1)  

set.seed(123456) 
e = rnorm(1000,0,1)  

set.seed(123456) 
y = 4 + 0.3*x + e
```

or just set the seed once and define all the variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s recommended to only set the random seed *once*.

From then on you can use it to generate random numbers freely.

Now, to *reproduce* the exact same sequence of random numbers you need to

1. Seed the generator with the same seed,
2. Use the same random number generator (via `RNGKind`; you would normally not touch this in R),
3. perform the exact same sequence of calls to functions that consume random numbers.

That last point is important: Setting the same random seed but performing a different sequence of calls, will yield different random numbers. For instance:

```
set.seed(12345)
runif(10)
rnorm(10)

set.seed(12345)
runif(5)
rnorm(10)
```

… this will yield *different* random numbers for the `rnorm` calls.